# Laravel Relación entre tablas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Cuando relleno un nuevo registro, en vez de salirme el nombre en cuestion del registro foraneo, sale su clave principal, se supone que debo de traducirlo con las relaciones.

> MovimientosController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $movimientos = Movimiento::orderBy('codigo', 'ASC')->paginate(15);
    $movimientos->each(function($movimientos){
        $movimientos->producto;
        $movimientos->proyecto;
        $movimientos->ubicacion;
    });

    return view('admin.movimientos.index')->with('movimientos', $movimientos);

}
```

> Movimiento.php

```
class Movimiento extends Model
{

public $primaryKey = 'codigo';

protected $table = "movimientos";

protected $fillable = ['fecha','hora','tipo','codigo_producto','cantidad','albaran','acronimo','ubicacion','codigo_ticket','puo','codigo_proyecto'];

    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Producto');
    }

    public function proyecto()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Proyecto');
    }

    public function ubicacion()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Ubicacion');
    }
}
```

> Producto.php

```
class Producto extends Model
{

    public $primaryKey = 'codigo';

    protected $table = "productos";

    protected $fillable = ['nombre','nombre_corto','codigo_familia','unidad','fungible','codigo_proveedor','stock_minimo','codigo_ubicacion_default'];

    public function familia()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Familia');
    }

    public function proveedor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Proveedor');
    }

    public function ubicacion()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Ubicacion');
    }

    public function movimiento()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Movimiento');
    }

    public function puo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PUO');
    } 

    public function proyectos()               
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Proyecto');
    }
}
```

> Ubicacion.php

```
class Ubicacion extends Model
{
    protected $table = "ubicaciones";

    public $primaryKey = 'codigo';

    protected $fillable = ['acronimo','DCM_Store'];

    public function producto()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Producto');
}

    public function movimiento()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Movimiento');
}    
}
```

> Proyecto.php

```
class Proyecto extends Model
{

    public $primaryKey = 'id_proyecto';

    protected $table = "proyectos";

    protected $fillable = ['nombre'];

    public function movimiento()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Movimiento');
    }

    public function puo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Puo');
    } 

    public function productos()   
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Producto');
    }
}
```

> Index.blade.php (Movimiento)

@extends('admin.template.main')

```
@section('title', 'Listado de Movimientos')

@section('content')
<a href="{{ route('movimientos.create') }}" class="btn btn-info">Registrar nuevo Movimiento</a><hr>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Código de Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Albarán</th>
      <th>Acrónimo</th>
      <th>Ubicación</th>
      <th>Código del Ticket</th>          
      <th>PUO</th>
      <th>Código del Proyecto</th>          
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        @foreach($movimientos as $movimiento)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->codigo }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->fecha }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->hora }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->tipo }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->codigo_producto->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->cantidad }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->albaran }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->acronimo }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->ubicacion->DCM_Store }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->codigo_ticket }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->puo }}</td>
                <td>{{ $movimiento->proyecto->nombre }}</td>                                                            
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('movimientos.edit', $movimiento->codigo) }}" class="btn btn-warning"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    <a href="{{ route('movimientos.destroy', $movimiento->codigo) }}" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true" onclick="return confirm('¿Seguro que quieres borrarlo')"></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
{!! $movimientos->render() !!}

@endsection
```

Y me enseña este error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/almacen/resources/views/admin/movimientos/index.blade.php)
```

Se supone que estoy llamando a las funciones que contienen las relaciones para que puedan relacionarse entre ellas, pero claro siempre me marca este error.

Añado mi intento con `with()`

```
    public function index()
{
    $movimientos = Movimiento::orderBy('codigo', 'ASC')->paginate(15);
    $movimiento = Movimiento::with('proyecto')->get();

    return view('admin.movimientos.index')->with('movimientos', $movimientos);

}

<td>{{ $movimiento->proyecto->nombre }}</td>  

Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/almacen/resources/views/admin/movimientos/index.blade.php)
```

Comment: Así es muy difícil ver que tienes. No muestras los modelos completos (Movimiento) ni  implicados (Productos). También decirte que para sacar asociados no se usa el each, sino "->with()"

Comment: Lo modifique todo un poco, con lo poco que avance y todo los archivos que utilizo.

Comment: qué versión de Laravel utilizas?

Comment: Utilizo la versión 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok entonces en conclusión:

Si en su modelo principal no se utiliza "id" como clave principal o desea unir el modelo secundario a una columna diferente, puede pasar un tercer argumento al método belongsTo que especifica la clave personalizada de su tabla primaria:

```
public function post(){
return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');}
```

Además, tratar de no especificar nombres que puedan interferir entre métodos, llaves o tablas.

Me alegra que lo hayas solucionado.

Comment: Si imprimo con `dd` estos campos me vienen como NULL por eso da error de `non-object`

Comment: En las migraciones está todo correctamente relacionado?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ehhD5 MovimientosController.php

https://imgur.com/a/77ODl Movimiento.php

https://imgur.com/a/iUyw6 Proyecto.php

https://imgur.com/a/pM09a Producto.php

https://imgur.com/a/aoEuF Ubicacion.php

https://imgur.com/a/Q2Bu7 Index.blade.php

https://imgur.com/a/RD5sk Movimientos.index

`Así es como esta ahora mismo`

Comment: Ok. Las migraciones que es encuentran dentro de la carpeta database/migrations/*, están relacionadas las tablas también?

Comment: Te paso la imagén https://imgur.com/a/Il8uy `Tabla movimientos` https://imgur.com/a/NzPuA `Tabla ubicaciones` https://imgur.com/a/Xcx3M `Tabla productos` https://imgur.com/a/V7uRD `Tabla Proyectos`

Comment: No se ve mal. En la base de datos es obvio que existe por lo menos un movimiento con su proyecto, ubicación y producto verdad? en el index del controlador haz un dd($movimientos->first()); que muestra?

Comment: Saca supongo que es si no me equivoco el `primer registro, por que tiene dos y el otro tiene código 7. `https://imgur.com/a/4RZqm`. Y si te fijas vienen los null de los campos que quiero traducir en su clave foranea. Y si en todas las tablas tengo al menos un registro introducido.

Answer (score 0):

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/almacen/resources/views/admin/movimientos/index.blade.php)
```

En la traza te saldra la linea en concreto que te falla, pero básicamente dice que un Modelo (objeto) tiene un valor nulo (no inicializado) y estas intentando a acceder a uno de sus atributos.

Ejemplo 1:

```
$movimiento->codigo
```

Si movimiento es nulo, al acceder a "codigo" te dará el error

Ejemplo 2:

```
$movimiento->codigo_producto->nombre
```

Suponiendo que movimiento no es nulo, pero que el "codigo_producto" si, dará el error porque no puede acceder a "nombre"

Comment: Si imprimo con dd($movimiento) no aparece null, y como miro la traza.

Comment: Lógica, no tiene porque ser el primero, prueba esto: 

if(is_null($movimiento))
 dd($movimiento);
endif

if(is_null($movimiento->codigo_producto))
 dd($movimiento,$movimiento->codigo_producto);
endif

Comment: Hice un `@foreach($movimientos as $movimiento)
{{dd($movimiento->producto)}}` y exactamente imprime `null`